# How to reset the checkbox, search text box and select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html page:

```
<form id="userworklog"  action="#" method="post">
    <div id="userlogs" class="userlogs">
        <table id="worklog">
            <tr>
                <th>Strt date</th>
                <th>Projects</th>
                <th>Charge# Field</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type= "date" id="startdate" name="startdate"  class="required">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="SearchBox" id="SearchBox" placeholder="Search...." />  
                    <br /> 
                    <select  id="projectsList" class="textFld" multiple="multiple"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"  id="comboBox" placeholder="Search.." />
                    <ul id="userList"  class="nobull" style="width: 300px; height: 80px;list-style: none; overflow: auto">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have submit and reset button. We are dynamically loading the data and populating to html. When I submit reset the input " start date" is only resetting. To reset the check list I used jQuery

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $("#checkbox").attr("checked", false);
});
```

I could reset the search of project and employee .unless I press enter the project list data is not viewed in the html

Comment: dont use id selector to reset the value of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#reset).on("click", function(){
    $('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);
})
```

This should reset the checkbox to false.
Please take a look here too: [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To reset the checkbox field use below jquery,

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

To reset the select list use below jquery,

```
$("#projectsList").prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

To reset the search text box use below jquery,

```
$("#SearchBox").val('');
```

Comment: Thank for your help.That helps me.

Comment: But i had a problem,for example : if

Comment: Thank for Search…
1.AB
2.BC
3.gvj

If I search for a..the table will display like
a
1.AB


If I click reset….




Until I press Enter in the search… It will display like that.
Search…
1.AB
2.BC
3.gvj
your help.That helps me.But i had a problem,for example : if